# Can't resolve gstatic.com.. in node_modules/firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, nuxt.js

does anyone know why this issue comes?

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app.js' in '<route to project>/node_modules/firebase'
```

versions:

```json
"firebase": "^9.14.0",
"@nuxtjs/firebase": "^8.2.2",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was showing up because I was using import statement for firebase 8

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firebase-messaging'
```

it should be like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";
```

Comment: Common issue indeed. Please accept your answer when you will be able to.